# Merge with input parameters in stored procedure - Oracle

Tags: oracle

I have a stored procedure that receives input parameters, with these parameters I need to insert or update a table. This is my code but it gives me error

```
procedure prc_registro(pi_solicitud             solicitud.id % TYPE,
                       pi_fecha_inicio_vigencia pedido.fecha_inicio_vigencia % TYPE,
                       pi_fecha_fin_vigencia    pedido.fecha_fin_vigencia % TYPE,
                       pi_vigencia_Abierta      pedido.vigencia_abierta % TYPE,
                       pi_renovacion_auto       pedido.renovacion_automatica % TYPE) is
pragma autonomous_transaction;
l_id_movimiento     movimiento.id % type;
BEGIN
 begin
        select pm.id
          into l_id_movimiento
          from movimiento pm
         where pm.solicitud = pi_solicitud;
 end;
 
 merge into vigencia
      using (select pi_fecha_inicio_vigencia,
                    pi_fecha_fin_vigencia,
                    pi_vigencia_Abierta,
                    pi_renovacion_auto
               from dual) Y 
      on (vigencia.movimiento = l_id_movimiento)
      when matched then
        update
           set vigencia.fecha_inicio_vigencia = pi_fecha_inicio_vigencia,
               vigencia.fecha_fin_vigencia    = pi_fecha_fin_vigencia,
               vigencia.vigencia_abierta      = pi_vigencia_Abierta,
               vigencia.renovacion_automatica = pi_renovacion_auto
      when not matched then
        insert
          (poliza_movimiento,
           fecha_inicio_vigencia,
           fecha_fin_vigencia,
           vigencia_abierta,
           renovacion_automatica)
        values
          (l_id_movimiento,
           pi_fecha_inicio_vigencia,
           pi_fecha_fin_vigencia,
           pi_vigencia_Abierta,
           pi_renovacion_auto);
END;
```

I get the error:

> ORA-00904: "PI_RENOVACION_AUTO": Invalid identifier

I'm not sure if the way I've coded is the right one, thanks for your support and suggestions

Comment: Please provide minimal reproducible example: post DDL of the tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameters used in the usong without any alias are confusing the parser.
As you're only using parameters you can simplify the `USING` clause.
Instead of

```
using (select pi_fecha_inicio_vigencia,
                    pi_fecha_fin_vigencia,
                    pi_vigencia_Abierta,
                    pi_renovacion_auto
               from dual) Y
```

just use

```
using dual
```

Comment: Thanks you. I put a alias in each parameter within the dual